# How to automate fiddler and export results to local directory

Tags: fiddler

I am working on a client request where I need to capture web browser traffic using fiddler and export it to local drive.

I am enter some data in web browser and the same is captured as request in Fiddler session.

As per my understanding of Fiddler the script should execute as soon as any web session is captured.

In order to export the request from Fiddler I am using the below code in OnBeforeRequest function in Fiddler script

```
if(oSession.url =="www.google.com"){
oSession.utilDecodeRequest();   
oSession.SaveRequest("C:\\Downloads\request.txt",true);
oSession.SaveRequestBody("C:\\Downloads\requestBody.txt");
```

}

Any suggestion why the request is not getting saved as a text file as I have mentioned in the above code.

Comment: Welcome at Stackoverflow. Why are you unable to run fiddler script? What happens when you try to run it? Please show us (edit your question) what you tried and why it doesnt work.

Comment: Hi Felix, I am not able to export the request body to few captures by using the below code in the OnBeforeRequest(oSession: Session) function in the fiddler script. Can you please shade some light on the same.

Comment: if(oSession.url =="www.google.com"){
            oSession.utilDecodeRequest();   //Decoding HTTP request in case it's gzip
            //Saving full request object (Including HTTP headers)
            oSession.SaveRequest("C:\\Downloads\\request.txt",true);
            //Saving just body
            oSession.SaveRequestBody("C:\\Downloads\\requestBody.txt");
        }

Comment: okay. Lets re-read my comment. "please edit your question". Make it easy for people to help you by giving them the information they need.

Comment: Done. Felix please have a look if the question is clearer and suggest some solution if you are aware of this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file is getting generated successfully. There was admin right issue.

Re installed fiddler with admin rights and the files got generated successfully.